# How to Get Database Names With all Tables and procedures,views etc in c# Tree view

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Actually I want to fetch Database Names just like in SQL Management Studio have on the left Spinner Bar same as in C# tree View.

I am working on a system in which database control through Application,
so I fetched all database Names and All Tables Names but I not getting each Database with their tables, just like in SQL Management Studio, in which A database have 4 to 5 nodes includes(tables,views,procedures,etc). and also I fetched in a List so I want to fetch in a tree View just Like in SQL Management Studio.

for Backend(Business Logic) I used this and fetched All Database Names and all Tables without respective sequences.

```
 public List<string> GetDatabaseList()
        {
            List<string> list = new List<string>();
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(MyConString))
            {
                con.Open();
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT name from 
sys.databases", con))
                {
                    using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (dr.Read())
                        {
                            list.Add(dr[0].ToString());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return list;
        }

 public List<string> GetTableList()
        {
            List<string> list = new List<string>();
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(MyConString))
            {
                con.Open();
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT name from 
sys.Tables", con))
                {
                    using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (dr.Read())
                        {
                            list.Add(dr[0].ToString());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return list;
        }
```

and use it by front-end through anycomponents.datasource.

My expected output is that I want to get all respective nodes of database Just like in SQL Management Studio not only database and tables.

Comment: Have you tried: `SELECT * FROM sys.objects;` Which gives you all objects from database. The Type Column will tell you weather it is a view, a table, a constraint, etc.... Have a further look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-objects-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: yes,I tried this,but the list shown all things in one, is there anyway to display with relevant ? means parent Node>database name then child nodes contains tables,views,procedures etc same like in sql Management Studio

Comment: Would it not be easier to construct the tree in c#? You'll need a recursive CTE to do it in SQL, but seems like c# is where you should do it..

Comment: Use Get Schema which give the entire database structure.  See msdn : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.getschema?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 0):

Well if you use `sys.objects` it'll list all database related objects. The only trick you need is to have a `sysadmin` account that can view all databases. Then, you can just target each database objects.

So, what you'll need is :

1. Get databases names list
2. Target each database objects
3. Filter objects as needed.

Here is a working example.

```
public enum DbObjectType
{
    SYSTEM_TABLE,
    USER_TABLE,
    VIEW,
    SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE
}
public class SqlServerDbObjects
{
    const string connectionString = @"Data Source=.\;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True";
    public IDictionary<string, IList<string>> GetDbObjects()
    {
        var dbNameList = GetDatabaseList();

        var dbObj = new Dictionary<string, IList<string>>();

        for (int x = 0; x < dbNameList.Count; x++)
        {
            var name = dbNameList[x];

            var objList = GetDatabaseObjectsList(name, DbObjectType.USER_TABLE);

            dbObj.Add(name, objList);
        }

        return dbObj;

    }
    public IList<string> GetDatabaseList()
    {
        const string sql = "SELECT [name] FROM sys.databases WHERE database_id > 4";

        return Reader(sql, "name");
    }
    public IList<string> GetDatabaseObjectsList(string databaseName, DbObjectType objType)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(string.Empty);

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(databaseName))
            throw new NullReferenceException("You must specify a database");
        else
            sb.Append($"SELECT [name] FROM [{databaseName}].sys.objects WHERE [type_desc] = '{objType.ToString()}'");

        return Reader(sb.ToString(), "name");
    }
    public IList<string> Reader(string query, string columnName)
    {
        var list = new List<string>();

        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
            {
                connection.Open();

                using (SqlDataReader dataReader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (dataReader.Read())
                    {
                        list.Add(dataReader[columnName].ToString());
                    }
                }


            }

            return list;
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            // do stuff for handling sql errors.
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

Then you just do :

```
var test =  new SqlServerDbObjects().GetDbObjects();
```

I have tried to make it as simple as I could, so you can get the idea.